# Threads vs fork wordlist read and hash

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

Why is in this case fork way better than threads? With a file of 139 mb (rockyou.txt) fork is 0.5 seconds, with the same file and the same word at the end of the file it's 3 second with thread (measured with both clock () and normal stopwatch, threads take much longer than the fork)
The program reads each line of a wordlist, hash it and compare with a digest.
This one is with fork

```
void wordlistFork(char digest[], char hashtype[], FILE *wordlist,int numberOfFork){
    int i;
    clock_t t;
    fseek(wordlist, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long fileLength = ftell(wordlist);
    fseek(wordlist, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    for(i=0;i<numberOfFork;i++){
        int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
            char line[512];
            long initialOffset = correctOffset(lengthOfFile*i/numberOfFork,wordlist);
            long finalOffset = correctOffset(lengthOfFile*(i+1)/numberOfFork,wordlist);
            fseek(wordlist, initialOffset, SEEK_SET);
            t = clock();
            while (initialOffset < finalOffset) {
                fscanf(wordlist,"%s\n",line);
                char tempLine[512] = {0};
                strncpy(tempLine,line,strlen(line));
                if (strcmp(hash(tempLine,hashType), digest) == 0) {
                    printf("Child %d: Trovato! hash %s %s -> %s\n",i, tipohash, digest, linea);
                    t = clock() -t;
                    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                    printf("Time elapsed: %f seconds\n",time_taken);
                    system("killall hashcrack");
                    return;
                }
                initialOffset = ftell(wordlist);
            }
            printf("Child %d Found nothing.\n",i);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<numberOfFork;i++)
        wait(NULL);
}
```

This one is with threads

```
for(i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void *(*)(void *)) crack, (void *)(intptr_t) i);
for(i=0;i<numberOfThreads;i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);  

void *crack(const int *args){
    int threadID = (int)(intptr_t)args;
    char line[512];
    FILE *wordlist = fopen(Tpath,"r");
    long initialOffset = correctOffset(fileLength*threadID/numberOfThreads,wordlist);
    long finalOffset = correctOffset(fileLength*(threadID+1)/numberOfThreads,wordlist);
    fseek(wordlist, initialOffset, SEEK_SET);
    while (initialOffset < FinalOffset) {
        fscanf(wordlist,"%s\n",line);
        char tempLine[512] = {0};
        strncpy(tempLine,line,strlen(line));
        if (strcmp(hash(tempLine,hashType), Tdigest) == 0) {
            printf("Thread %d: Found! hash %s %s -> %s\n",threadID, hashType, Tdigest, line);
            system("killall hashcrack");
            exit(0);
        }
        initialOffset = ftell(wordlist);
    }
    printf("Thread %d: found nothing.\n",threadID);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of masochistically recasting the same variable over and over and over and over, just declare a local with that type, or even better, change the argument's type to match what it is.

Comment: @tadman The problem is in the while, in the while I think I'm not recasting anything. Which line are you talking about?

Comment: `(struct params *)args` shows up way too many times. This code ends up just clutter and noise because of habits like that. Since you're constrained by the thread function signature, just declare `struct params* args = args_v` and change the argument to `void* v_args`. Voila, no more recasting required!

Comment: @tadman I did a better thing, I used global variables instead of passing it in a struct and doing 1000 castings. But the result is exactly the same, 0.5 seconds with fork and 3 seconds with threads to find the same word in the same file at the same position using 6 fork or 6 thread in a CPU with 12 virtual cores with no SIMD. At least now the code is nicer ahahah, but I can't understand the main point of the question

Comment: @tadman I also updated the code, if you have any other suggestions I'm all ears

Comment: OT: this is a good example of why `strncpy` is almost never right: `strncpy(tempLine,line,strlen(line))`. Presumably you're doing that to protect against overrunning `tempLine` but you're not limiting the copy to `sizeof tempLine`, so if `line` is too long it will overrun. So, no protection at all. But worse, you tell `strncpy` to write at most `strlen(line)` bytes, which means *it will never write a trailing NUL*. So not only are you not protecting against buffer overrun, you're opening the possibility of an unterminated string.

Comment: You could "fix" that by using `strncpy(tempLine, line, sizeof(tempLine)-1)`. But look at what happens: the initialisation of `tempLine` writes 512 zeros. Then the copy writes a few bytes of useful data, and fills in the rest of `tempLine` with 0, because that's what `strncpy` does. Result: almost 1kb of zeros written, when you needed to write exactly one. That's probably not the worst inefficiency in the world, but it's certainly not helping your performance.

Comment: @rici I tried with the debugger, it's identical

Comment: @rici Maybe if I try to use a pointer instead of an array it's better, so I can create an array of the dimension of the read string +1 at runtime, but I don't want to risk heap overflow or something like this

Comment: What I'm saying is that strncpy is not helping you avoid overflow. That's not something you can check with a couple of test cases in the debugger. You need to use the right tests cases, at least.

Comment: The fork version does not reopen the file, so all processes share the same file pointer (but separate library buffers), so after the initial blocks read from the file by the C library all processes search the same section of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code's performance is indeterminate and based on the order in which work happens to get done. It probably just so happens that in one case the end of the file gets tested first and in the other case the beginning gets tested first. Your code doesn't enforce any particular order, so it's heavily dependent on quirks of scheduling order.

It's like if you test searching identical gardens, using two different algorithms, for a hidden egg. If the egg is in the same place each time, an algorithm that just happens to search where the egg is earlier in its search pattern will always win, even if it's not a better algorithm.

Comment: My code enforce a particulare order, there's the fseek, I split the file into n parts and then move the seek to the part of the specific thread / fork

Comment: @helloworld Your code doesn't enforce any order. Each thread or process has a particular chunk of the file that it will search and those threads/processes run in no particular order that your code enforces. The file might get searched from beginning to end or it might get searched from end to beginning. Your code doesn't enforce it.

Comment: I'm not understanding, I divide the file in chunks and the I read from the initial offset to the final offset, not vice versa, but ok, maybe the OS can decide to read from the final offset to the initial, I don't know. But, is there something I can do or not? To verify what are you saying or to make threads do better

Comment: @helloworld You don't read from the initial offset to the final offset. You dispatch a bunch of individual workers, each of which starts at a different point in the file. As for whether there is something you can do, I don't see how I can answer that without knowing what it is you're trying to do. Your code is searching around randomly for something -- how long it takes is totally based on luck. You could search in an enforced order, but that won't make the code any better. What's the problem? Your conclusion that one method is faster than the other is wrong, so what's the issue?

Comment: The problem is that maybe I'm wrong to do something with pthread. I have 6 cores, each core has a chunk of file and with the instruction  "while (initialOffset < finalOffset)" I say each thread/fork must read from initialOffset to finalOffset of a chunk, so the order should be the same, or at least not so much different in time. The instruction are executed in parallel, so there is no difference between which thread go first. Why are you saying that they start at a different point in the file if I'm doing the fseek? But that's okay, I trust you

Comment: Also, if I lock at the start of the function and I unlock at the end it prints in order, so it's not random

Comment: Ok I executed perf profiler, in thread case there is a lot of overhead, so I think that is the problem. First two lines

threads: Samples: 90K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 65258804164
  Children      Self  Command    Shared Object           Symbol
+   57,69%     0,00%  hashcrack  [unknown]               [k] 0000000000000000  ◆
+   52,55%     5,60%  hashcrack  libc-2.31.so            [.] __vsprintf_interna▒  
  
fork: 
Samples: 13K
  32,72%  hashcrack  libc-2.31.so        [.] __vfprintf_internal
   7,80%  hashcrack  libc-2.31.so        [.] _IO_default_xsputn

Comment: "*The instruction are executed in parallel, so there is no difference between which thread go first.*". Really? So what position of the file is read first by the disk?

Comment: There is no reason why with threads the disk should read at the end and with forks at the beginning, also because I tried and it gives exactly the same results with another disk. The profiler says that with threads there is more overhead than fork, but normally it's more overhead to create a process than a thread. That's what I don't understand

Comment: "*There is no reason why with threads the disk should read at the end and with forks at the beginning*". Exactly. There is no reason the code should execute in any particular order, and the performance depends critically on the order in which the code executes.